# Filter Array of ManagedObject FetchResults in Swift

Tags: swift, nsarray, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

In objective-C you can filter an array of fetched results from core data as follows:

```
NSString *brand = @"honda";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
        @"brand like %@", brand]; 
NSArray *filteredArray = [results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

I am trying to do something similar in Swift but am getting various errors:

```
let myResults = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
let idPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id >= 1000")
let idArray = (myResults as Array).filtered(using: idPredicate)
```

I have tried casting in various ways such as `myResults as Sales` but still get a an assortment of errors:

**Edit:**

With the above version, I get a series of fix-it suggestions, beginning with replace 'using' with "" that lead to more errors if I accept any suggestions.  When instead of as Array, I write as Sales or alternatively write idArray: Sales, I get 'Cannot force cast Array to Sales'

What is the proper syntax to do this in either Swift 3 or 4?

Comment: What are the errors? [Edit] your question showing full details.

Comment: Apply the predicate **before** the fetch to the fetch request. Databases are optimized to filter stuff.

Comment: I was able to filter without predicate using   var filteredArray = myResults.filter { $0.id.intValue >=1000 }.  @vadian would you expect this to be noticeably less efficient than a predicate in the fetch?

Comment: Yes I do. It's highly recommended to filter with a fetch predicate.